# My XML stopped loading in Flash

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

I had a project which was successfully loading images from an XML file to make a Flash gallery.  However, it seems to have suddenly stopped working.  I've done troubleshooting and found that it is because the SWF is no longer loading the XML file.  However, I had not messed with the SWF.  I went into the FLA file and the code was the same.  Here it is, for a reference.

```
var strTitle = "THIS IS TITLE TEXT";
var strDescription = "This is descriptive";
var intCurrent = 0;
var arrDescription = new Array();//Stores descriptions
var arrTitle = new Array();//Stores titles
var arrMainLoc = new Array();//Stores image locations
var arrThumbLoc = new Array();//Stores thumb locations

var intCurrent:Number = 0;//Used to store the number passed from the button press

stop();
System.security.allowDomain("http:/gretchencomlydesign.com");

myPhoto = new XML();
myPhoto.ignoreWhite = true;
myPhoto.load("imgDATA.xml");
myPhoto.onLoad = function(success)
{
trace("loaded");
var intImageCount = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes.length;
for (i = 0; i < intImageCount; i++)
{
    arrDescription[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.desc;
    arrTitle[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.titl;
    arrMainLoc[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.main;
    arrThumbLoc[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.thumbs;
    //trace(arrTitle[i]);   //Tests Loaded titles
    //trace(arrDescription[i]);    //Tests Loaded descriptions
}
play();
//trace(myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.desc);
  };
  myPhoto.onLoad = function(false)
  {
    trace("XML failed to load");
  };
```

It did load, but now will no longer work.  I checked and the server is Apache, and my case matches.  My file is named "imgDATA.xml".  Has anybody ever experienced anything like this?

EDIT:  It's worth mentioning that I tried changing the name of the target XML file and the XML file to be loaded, and it still wouldn't load.

Edit 2:  After tweaking the SWF code, I get this output

```
loaded
onData:<pop>



<img titl="0" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/0.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/0.jpg"/>

<img titl="1" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/1.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/1.jpg"/>

<img titl="2" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/2.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/2.jpg"/>

<img titl="3" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/3.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/3.jpg"/>





</pop>
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<pop>

<img titl="0" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/0.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/0.jpg"/>
<img titl="1" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/1.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/1.jpg"/>
<img titl="2" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/2.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/2.jpg"/>
<img titl="3" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/3.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/3.jpg"/>


</pop>
```

Comment: remove the "http:/" from allowDomain. don't know if that's the problem but it's wrong. and try to use only lowercase letters in filenames.

Comment: that didn't do it, but thanks

Comment: @Nick you should also consider using AS3 as opposed to AS2.

Comment: where does your swf reside on the server? and where the xml? are they in the same folder?

Comment: The XML and SWF are supposed to be in the same folder, and they are.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `crossdomain.xml` file at the root of your server (the one that hosts your XML file)? If not, you need to add it and set its content to something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**Edit:**

Try setting all the event handlers to get a better idea of what's happening, then post the result of the trace statements here.

```
myPhoto.onData = function(src:String) { trace("onData:" + src); }
myPhoto.onHTTPStatus = function(httpStatus:Number) { trace("httpStatus:" + httpStatus); }
myPhoto.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) { trace("onLoad:" + success); }
```

**Edit:**

Try adding a header to your XML file, otherwise Flash might not know it's XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pop>
<img titl="0" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/0.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/0.jpg"/>
<img titl="1" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/1.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/1.jpg"/>
<img titl="2" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/2.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/2.jpg"/>
<img titl="3" desc="" main="pics/pop/main/3.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/3.jpg"/>
</pop>
```

Comment: i think he's loading it from the same domain - so no need for a crossdomain file

Comment: I am.  I just put that in there to see if it would do anything, and forgot to remove it.

Comment: It didn't mention where is the SWF and where is the XML, so I just made a guess. If someone deleted or changed the crossdomain file it could explain why his SWF stopped working even though he didn't change it.

Comment: I messed with the XML file, but I don't think I did anything to it other than change some destinations.  Nothing that would make it unloadable, or which would disrupt Flash's loading capabilities, I imagine.  Here is the text

<pop>
 
<img titl=0" desc=" main="pics/pop/main/0.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/0.jpg"/>
<img titl=1" desc=" main="pics/pop/main/1.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/1.jpg"/>
<img titl=2" desc=" main="pics/pop/main/2.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/2.jpg"/>
<img titl=3" desc=" main="pics/pop/main/3.jpg" thumbs="pics/pop/thumbs/3.jpg"/>


</pop>

Comment: I don't know if this is the exact XML feed or not, but I see many mistakes. `titl=0"` has a closing quote but no opening one, all the `desc="` have no value and only one quote instead of two, etc. You can check the validity of your XML there: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp

Comment: I just fixed that, and there are no more errors.  However, it isn't even being loaded by flash

Comment: So the problem is fixed? You are getting the whole XML in onData(), right?

Comment: Everything is still coming up undefined when I test it.  I added an array trace right after the for loop and it came back undefined

Comment: So it means Flash cannot parse your XML file. Could you post it in your question (exactly as it is on your server)?

Comment: You should try adding an XML declaration to your file. I've updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the problem.  I just had to tweak the code so that it made a function, then called the function.  That got it parsing.  Here is the working code

```
var strTitle = "THIS IS TITLE TEXT";
var strDescription = "This is descriptive";
var intCurrent = 0;
var arrDescription = new Array();//Stores descriptions
var arrTitle = new Array();//Stores titles
var arrMainLoc = new Array();//Stores image locations
var arrThumbLoc = new Array();//Stores thumb locations

var intCurrent:Number = 0;//Used to store the number passed from the button press

stop();




function processXMLData(success)
{
  if (success)
  {trace("loaded");
    var intImageCount = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes.length;

    for (i = 0; i < intImageCount; i++)
    {
        arrDescription[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.desc;
        arrTitle[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.titl;
        arrMainLoc[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.main;
        arrThumbLoc[i] = myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.thumbs;
        trace(arrTitle[i]);//Tests Loaded titles
        trace(arrDescription[i]);//Tests Loaded descriptions

    }
    trace(arrTitle[0]);
    play();
    //trace(myPhoto.firstChild.childNodes[0].attributes.desc);
}    else
  {
    content="Today's news is not found";
  }
  }



var myPhoto=new XML();
myPhoto.ignoreWhite=true;
myPhoto.onLoad=processXMLData;
myPhoto.load("imgDATA.xml");
stop();
```